# where does the arguments of execl() passed to?

Tags: c++, c, unix, system-calls

Under the context of system programming in UNIX environment, while using the programming language C++, in my understanding, execl() will pass in the path of the program it will run, and a vector. When that vector is being passed in, I understand it as being passed into the entry point, which is usually the main function. In a main function, I understand that my parameters can be written as:

```
int main(int argc, int* argv[]){ return 0; }
```

With the above context in mind, when arguments are being passed into the execl(), it seems to me that it doesn't get directly passed into the main function.

Is there a "processing" stage where arguments of execl() are changed to integer data type and an array?

At the same time, if there's any faults in my understanding, please, feel free to correct them.

Comment: The main signature you're claiming is wrong, itt's always `int main(int argc, char* argv[]){ return 0; } `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature you give for the `main` function is incorrect.  It should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

Or:

```
int main(void);
```

As for the arguments, the arguments passed to `execl` should match what the called program receives.

For example, if program A execs program B like this:

```
execl("/path/to/progB", "progB", "-a", "1", "-x", "hello", "command", (char *)NULL);
```

Then in program B, `argc` will be 6 and `argv` will essentially be:

```
 { "progB", "-a", "1", "-x", "hello", "command" }
```

Comment: Don't forget to cast the `NULL`  `(char *) NULL`

Comment: @SeekAddo  Good catch.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

`main` takes a `char*argv[]` argument (not `int *argv[]`) just like the usual core exec sysccall usually does. On Linux, the system call is `execve` (requires a `char*[]`)and all other exec* functions are implemented in terms of that.

As for `execl`, the argument list is required to be NULL-terminated, which allows you to count the arguments and then copy them into an array that gets passed down to `execve`.

The musl libc library does that rather straightforwardly: https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/process/execl.c

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is wrong. From this [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) the argument list is always a number of null-terminated `char*` pointers (emphasis mine):

> > `execl(<shell path>, arg0, file, arg1, ..., (char *)0);`
> >
> > where  is an unspecified pathname for the sh utility, file is the >> process image file, and for execvp(), where arg0, arg1, and so on correspond to the values passed to execvp() in argv[0], argv[1], and so on.
> >
> > The arguments represented by arg0,... are pointers to **null-terminated character strings.** These strings shall constitute the argument list available to the new process image. The list is terminated by a null pointer. The argument arg0 should point to a filename string that is associated with the process being started by one of the exec functions.

So that doesn't match what you're claiming:

> ```
> int main(int argc, int* argv[]){ return 0; } 
>                 // ^^^^
> ```